# Complicated query with multiple cell values (across rows) as a condition?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, datastore

1.) I want to query, which fk_pathway ids contain all 3 fk_link ids (101,51,87). in this example **the result would be pathway id 2 and pathway id 3.**

2.) I want to query, which fk_pathway ids contain all 3 fk_link ids (101,51,87) in ascending order. in this example **the result would be pathway id 3.**

The query should be possible with any number of fk_link ids, so that I could get the parent fk_pathway ids of thousands of fk_link ids.

Is this even possible with MySql? In case it isn't, is there some other form of php-compatible data storage, where I could make such queries?

Simplified version of data:

```
  fk_link | fk_pathway | order
      101   1            1
       51   1            2

      101   2            1 
       87   2            2
       51   2            3
       29   2            4         

       11   3            1
      101   3            2
       51   3            3
       87   3            4
       97   3            5
```

Comment: And you have tried...?

Comment: if you have multiple questions, you should post them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `fk_pathway` which have all the three `fk_link`s, use:

```
select
    fk_pathway
from your_table
group by
    fk_pathway
where fk_link in (101,51,87)
having count(distinct fk_link) = 3
```

If you want to get highest `fk_pathway` which has all the three `fk_link`s, use:

```
select
    fk_pathway
from your_table
group by
    fk_pathway
where fk_link in (101,51,87)
having count(distinct fk_link) = 3
order by fk_pathway desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part has been answered by GurV.

For the second part you also need to check if the order of 101 < order of 51 < order of 87, for a fk_pathway. To do so, add comparison conditions in the `having` clause.

```
select fk_pathway
from your_table
group by fk_pathway 
having count(distinct case when fk_link in (101,51,87) then fk_link end) = 3
and max(case when fk_link=101 then order end) < max(case when fk_link=51 then order end)
and max(case when fk_link=51 then order end) < max(case when fk_link=87 then order end)
```